# Difference between savepoint and checkpoint in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I know there are similar questions on the stackoverflow,but after investigating several of them, I know

1. `savepoint` is triggered manually, while `checkpoint` is triggered 
   automatically
2. They are using different storage format

But these are not the confusing points,I have no idea when to use one or when to use the other.

Consider the following two scenarios:

1. If I need to shutdown or restart the whole application for some reason(eg bug fix or crash unexpected) , then I will have to use `savepoint` to restore the whole application?
2. I thought that `checkpoint` is only used internally in Flink  for fault tolerance when application is running, that is, the application itself is running, but tasks or other things may fail， that is, Flink will use `checkpoint` for state recovery?
3. There is also `externalized checkpoint`, I think it is the same with `savepoint` in functionality, that is, `externalized checkpoint` can also be used to recover from a restarted application?

Answer (score 2):

> Does Flink use checkpoint for state recovery?

Basically you're right. As you said, the checkpoint is usually used internally in Flink for fault tolerance and it's more like a concept inside the framework. When your application fails, the program will try to restart from the latest checkpoint. That's how checkpoint works in Flink, without any mannual interfering.

> Should I use savepoint to restore the whole application for bug fix?

Yes. In these cases, you don't want to restore from the checkpoint because maybe the latest checkpoint occurs several minutes ago. Instead, you'd like to snapshot the current the state of the whole application and restart it from the latest savepoint, which may be the quickest way to restore the application without too much delay.

> Externalized checkpoint.

It's still the checkpoint, but will be persisted externally based on your configurations. It can be used to restore the application, but the states are not so real time because there exists an interval between checkpoints.

For more information, take a look at this blog artical: https://data-artisans.com/blog/differences-between-savepoints-and-checkpoints-in-flink.

Comment: Thanks @bupt-ljy for the great answer.If my application may crash unexpected, so that I will not be able to get a chance to prepare savepoint manually in time,in this case, Looks I have no choice but to to use checkpoint?(As you said, there may be some delay because  there exists an interval between checkpoints) .

Comment: @bupt-ljy, another related question but more direct, checkpoint is used for fault tolerance,does `for fault tolerance` includes the scenario that the whole application crashed unexpectedly?

Comment: @Tom Sorry for replying so late. For the first question, If your application crashes unexpectedly(already retried several times), externalized checkpoint is the only way to recover it. For the second question, it includes the case you mentioned after you enable externalized checkpoint, otherwise it can only handle some cases that need retries like temporary network problem.